# Unable to write XML back after modification

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am reading a XML and changing some attributes. Then I am writing it back to file as XML and it returns me a blank file. If I don't modify the node it works fine. What I am doing wrong, please advice.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                        .newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(origDrXML);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("log");
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    NodeList children = nodes.item(i).getChildNodes();
int len = children.getLength();
for (int j = 0; j <= children.getLength(); j++) {
    if (children.item(j).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("directory"))
        children.item(j).setTextContent("D:\\Logs");
    }
 } // End of Childrens of <log>
} // End of <log> Tag */
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
transformer.transform(source, result);
String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
System.out.println(xmlString);
```

Comment: You are not writing it back to a file. Do you mean the written StringWriter is empty?

Comment: Yes StringWriter is empty

Comment: You're missing an open brace on the if statement.

Comment: The for loop condition should be `j < children.getLength()`, not `<=`. You're requesting a child beyond the end of the node list, and it's returning null.

Comment: I also suspect that you may have been swallowing the NPE in your code, which is why you didn't see it? Is this actually all wrapped in a try/catch that catches Exception and ignores it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with a null check?

```
for (int j = 0; j <= children.getLength(); j++) {
    if(children.item(j) != null ) {
            if (children.item(j).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("directory"))
                    children.item(j).setTextContent("D:\\Logs");
    }
}
```

This works for me!

Comment: It turns out the null check is necessary because the loop condition is incorrect.

Comment: You are very true. Now the code works great and thanks a ton.

Comment: however you could have avoided the check if you use David's suggestion of j< children.getLength !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `writer.flush()` before calling `writer.toString()`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the DOM `LSSerializer` mechanism instead of a `Transformer`.  Replace all this:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
transformer.transform(source, result);
String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
```

with this

```
LSSerializer ser =
    ((DOMImplementationLS)doc.getImplementation()).createLSSerializer();
String xmlString = ser.writeToString(doc);
```